# How to enable SOAP on a web-hosting that don't support SOAP

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap, web-hosting, zend-soap

In my php5 web-application i use zend mailMerge for constructing doc/pdf files from user data. Unfortunately, when i write a code, browser throws me an error: 
**"Uncaught exception 'Zend_Soap_Client_Exception' with message 'SOAP extension is not loaded."** 
I contacted with my hosting provider and asked about installation soap. He told me that my hosting doesn't support soap.
Also i found a "nusoap" library. As written there, this library can help if server don't support soap. But after enabling this library in my web-application, nothing changes.

So,if possible, how to enable SOAP on a web-hosting that don't support SOAP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using NuSOAP, your application must be programmed to use the NuSOAP library. My guess is that your application is programmed for the regular SOAP lib and therefore needs to be rewritten if you're going to use NuSOAP instead.

You cannot load the regular SOAP library if it isn't already installed on the server.

Did your hosting company give any good reason for not enabling SOAP?

Comment: they just said that it's not supported :(